# connect to docker's running container

Tags: docker

I downloaded centos/centos7.1.1503 from docker's official hub, and created my custom dockerfile as below.

```
FROM centos:centos7.1.1503
RUN yum install -y passwd
RUN echo -e “root\nroot” | (passwd --stdin root)
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y git-core build-essential libssl-dev
CMD /var/tmp | git clone git://git.openwrt.org/14.07/openwrt.git
```

I then ran the following 3 commands

```
docker build -t centos:test
docker run centos:test
docker attach <containerid>
```

It asks me for a password. The password i set in the docker file doesn't work at all. Any idea?

Comment: What's password it asks for? Centos root password or Git account password?

Comment: and what is `/var/tmp` in your container?

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to change this line

```
RUN echo -e “root\nroot” | (passwd --stdin root)
```

to this one:

```
RUN echo root | passwd root --stdin
```

Otherwise you are trying to set `root\nroot` as your root password (including that strange newline).

An other try would be this (if you have `xargs`available):

```
RUN echo root | xargs passwd root
```

Comment: You could also try: `RUN echo "root:root" | chpasswd` if you have that available.